# Complete categories, a continuous functor and a (complete?) comma category. [Hint needed]

Tags: category-theory

This problem might be trivial but I'm stuck with it nonetheless.  I would be very grateful if someone could give me a **hint** (no spoilers please):

Suppose $
\mathbf{C}$ is a *complete* category, $\mathbf{D}$ any category and $U\colon\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{D}$ is a *continuous* functor (meaning that it preserves limits) and fix any object $X\in\mathbf{D}$.  Our task is to show that, under these assumptions, the category $(X\downarrow U)$ is then also a complete category.

Comment: It's hard to give a hint without seeing where you get stuck. If you're getting stuck at the beginning, the provided information suggests that you should somehow construct a diagram in $\mathbf{C}$, take its limit, and then apply $U$, right? Otherwise why would we need that $U$ is continuous?

Comment: Fair enough.  Yeah, that much is clear.  We'd need to construct a diagram $D\colon \mathbf{G}\to\mathbf{C}$ from one in $(X\downarrow U)$, take $L$ as its limit in $\mathbf{C}$ then $U(L)$ will be a limit of the diagram $UD$ in $\mathbf{D}$.

Comment: Might it be that, for some $\lambda\in\hom(X,UD(L))$ and a $C\in\mathbf{C}$, $(C,\lambda)$ is a limit of the original diagram in the comma category?

Comment: Yeah, in fact there should be a canonical such map. Think about how you get a diagram in $\mathbf{C}$ from one in the comma category.

Comment: Cool, I think I've got it now thanks to you @jgon.  So how do we mark this question as solved then?

Comment: @Jean-PierredeVilliers One nice thing you can do is to answer your own question.